# .txt subtitles/transcript in VLC 2.0?

Tags: vlc-media-player, subtitles

Yesterday I upgraded my VLC to 2.0. I was watching some video lectures of .mp4 format. The lectures were not having any subtitles but they provided me transcript in .txt files. 
I want them to be used as subtitles in VLC 2.0 but they aren't working!!
Is there any solution for opening .txt subtitles or transcript in VLC 2.0??

Comment: If your TXT files are in correct format http://matroska.org/technical/specs/subtitles/srt.html
then simply rename the file to .srt

Comment: no they are not!! they are just transcripts!!

Answer (score 1):

In a .srt file, we have the time-stamps which specifies which text to be displayed when and for how long (shown below).

> 0 00:00:40,874 --> 00:00:44,644 KELLER: Our father, who art in heaven,
>
> 1 00:00:44,645 --> 00:00:47,313 hallowed be thy name.
>
> 2 00:00:47,314 --> 00:00:49,482 Thy kingdom come,
>
> 3 00:00:49,483 --> 00:00:54,320 thy will be done on earth as it is in
>   heaven.

Whereas, in the transcript, there will be no such time-stamps.

Therefore, it is practically impossible to use transcript to display subtitles.
But, if you can work on that file, and create time-stamps (various online tools and softwares are available for this), you can convert txt file to srt.

Hope this helps. Comment if more info is needed.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be ideal, but Youtube has this functionality. If you have a decent connection/time, upload it as a private video, and then you you'll have the **Transcribe and Sync** option where you can upload your text and have Youtube's servers take care of the syncing.